# Python: Appending API Calls to Spreadsheet

Tags: python, api, append, klout

I'll start out by saying I'm very new to Python and programming in general but am very hands on in my learning style.

I would like to use Python to:

1. Gather an entire column of a spreadsheet into a list
2. Call to Klout's API to (a) Get the Klout User ID and (b) Get the Klout Score
3. Append those two variables in columns in the same spreadsheet

I have an API key, the spreadsheet data, Python, and the klout Python scripts

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE

Thanks to Lonely for his help with getting me this far. Now I just need to write my score results to a spreadsheet.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from klout import *
k=Klout('my_API_key')
book=open_workbook('path_to_file')
sheet0=book.sheet_by_index(0)
List1=sheet0.col_values(0)
for screen_name in List1:
    kloutId = k.identity.klout(screenName=screen_name).get('id')
    score = k.user.score(kloutId=kloutId).get('score')
    print screen_name, score
```

UPDATE 2

Have successfully put Twitter Screennames back into a new spreadsheet. Can't seem to get scores to display correctly. It's also stopping at 30 (which happens to be the request per second limit for Klout). Here's what I have right now.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt
from klout import *
k=Klout('My_API_Key')
book=open_workbook('Path_to_My_File')
sheet0=book.sheet_by_index(0)
List1=sheet0.col_values(0)
for screen_name in List1:
    kloutId = k.identity.klout(screenName=screen_name).get('id')
    score = k.user.score(kloutId=kloutId).get('score')
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')
i = -1
for n in List1:
    i = i+1
    sheet.write(i,0,n)
b = 0
score1 = int(score)
for x in xrange(score1):
    b = b+1
    sheet.write(b,1,x)

wbk.save("KScores.xls")
```

FINAL WORKING VERSION

With a ton of help from a personal contact who I credit most of the writing of this script too I now have a completed .py script.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt
from time import sleep
from klout import *

klout_con = Klout('API_KEY_HERE', secure=True)
book = open_workbook('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE_HERE')
sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
List1 = sheet0.col_values(0)

wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')

row = 0
for screen_name in List1:
    klout_id = klout_con.identity.klout(screenName=screen_name).get('id')
    score = klout_con.user.score(kloutId=klout_id).get('score')
    sheet.write(row, 0, screen_name)
    sheet.write(row, 1, score)
    row += 1
    print screen_name
    sleep(1)
    wbk.save('KScores.xls')
```

Thanks to the community and Adam who both helped me put this thing together. Was an excellent starter project.

Comment: What format is your spreadsheet in? .xls?

Comment: it's in .xls but can easily convert to .csv if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read excel... use XLRD

Take all id's in list format.

Read each one of them by using iteration like `for i in list with Klout_APi` like ...

```
score = k.user.score(kloutId=kloutId).get('score')
```

However a sample data would have been great...

Comment: The first two columns of the spreadsheet look similar to this

FULL NAME | TWITTER_ID |
Person1     TwitterHandle1
Person2     TwitterHandle2

XLRD looks like it gets the job done for reading.

Comment: I've used that package successfully to pull parts of the list but I have well over 400 twitter handles, will need to get them out of the spreadsheet for the API to be of much use.

Comment: This works. Is there a way to put a pause between calls so as not to go over the per second allotment?

Comment: How about time.sleep(60) which will put the iteration for sleep for some time and then will contiinue with the rest of them, Though I am not sure what is the limit.... really want to help and test this thing but behind firewall so you might have to wait ....

Comment: Lonely, klout works great. I was getting errors but they were actually caused by folks having inactive twitter usernames that returned 400 errors from klout and killed the process. After cleaning those up, everything worked nicely. Now I just need to write the scores to a spreadsheet. Reading up on xlwt docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`xlrd`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) you can read data from excel and [`xlwt`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966) for writing data to excels. Read their documentations. And for csv, there is a module [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the standard library.